# UICollectionView with vertically aligned sections and vertically aligned cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` and I want to create a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to it that will be just like in the picture, but I just can't do it.

The final result should be: There are sections and in each section there are few cells, no more then the `UICollectionView` width, I want each section to be vertically aligned to the previous section, but if the section is at the end of the `UICollectionView` and out of the bounds of the collection, I want it to draw in a new line, just as in the photo.

[image]

I've checked **mokagio** [UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout](https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout), it looks the same except the part of the sections, the cells horizontally aligned and each cells is kept in the bounds of the `UICollectionView`, the problem is when I change the size of the items (cells), it's just as a normal layout and the sections are right after the other vertically.

[image]

If I get that right, what I have to do is to set the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` `scrollDirection` to **Vertical** and change the layout inside the section, because now the cells are horizontally aligned like that:

[image]

I need to vertically align the cells inside each section and change the frame of the section to fit the new cells bounds, am I right?

Please can someone guide me on how to start? I've watched Ray Wenderlich videos / tutorials, but still get can't the hang of it.

Thanks in advance.